# Update Windows Software in Dockerfile

Tags: windows, docker

Often times Dockerfile are linked together using FROM statements.  There's no telling when the upstream will update their package with the latest security fixes.  I often include an 'apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade' in my Linux based Dockerfile(s).

What is the equivalent for a Dockerfile based on WindowsServerCore?

Answer (score 0):

Linux base images (like `ubuntu`, `alpine` etc.) are updated regularly, and so are the Windows ones. Typically, Microsoft will push updates every month on [Patch Tuesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday). You can see this history in the [tags on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/nanoserver/tags/).

Comment: Say you create image A (Or someone else on docker hub does) that is based on windowsservercore or ubuntu. Then say you create image B 'FROM imageA'. Image B will not be updated when windowsservercore (or ubuntu) is updated. It will only be updated after the entire chain is updated. In other words windowsservercore->imageA->imageB.  At least, that is my understanding.  Correct me if i'm wrong.